# How to pre-process the data to calculate Root Mean Squared Logarithmic Error?

Tags: python, machine-learning, metrics, logarithm

I'm trying to calculate the Root Mean Squared Logarithmic Error for which I have found few options, one is to use the sklearn metric: mean_squared_log_error and take its square root

```
np.sqrt(mean_squared_log_error( target, predicted_y ))
```

But I get the following error:

> Mean Squared Logarithmic Error cannot be used when targets contain negative values

I have also tried a solution from a Kaggle post:

```
import math

#A function to calculate Root Mean Squared Logarithmic Error (RMSLE)
def rmsle(y, y_pred):
    assert len(y) == len(y_pred)
    terms_to_sum = [(math.log(y_pred[i] + 1) - math.log(y[i] + 1)) ** 2.0 for i,pred in enumerate(y_pred)]
    return (sum(terms_to_sum) * (1.0/len(y))) ** 0.5
```

Same issue, this time I get a domain error.

In the same post they comment the following regarding the negative log issue:

> You're right. You have to transform y_pred and y_test to make sure they don't carry negative values.

> In my case, when predicting weather temperature (originally in Celsius degrees), the solution was to convert them to Kelvin degrees before calculating the RMSLE:

> ```
> rmsle(data.temp_pred + 273.15, data.temp_real + 273.15)
> ```

Is there any standard form of use this metric that allows to work with negative values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normalize both the arrays to range 0 to 1

If you're using scikit you can use `sklearn.preprocessing.minmax_scale`:

```
minmax_scale(arr, feature_range=(0,1))
```

Before you do this save the max and min value of arr. You could get back the actual value.

Eg:

```
normalized = (value - arr.min()) / (arr.max() - arr.min()) # Illustration
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you want. From the docs, `minmax_scale` **independently scales each feature**, but you want both `temp_pred` and `temp_real` to be scaled by the same amount.

Comment: @Kyle What do you mean by same amount?

Comment: if `temp_pred = [-2, 2, 3]` and `temp_real = [-3, 2, 3]` then ideally `-3` would scale to `0` and both arrays would scale based on `-3` being the lowest value (what I meant by the same). But since each feature is scaled independently, then `temp_pred` will scale based on `-2` being the lowest value and `temp_real` will scale based on `-3` being the lowest value. I have not used `minmax_scale` extensively, but based on the documentation this is what I think it will do.

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard form that allows negative values because the log of a negative number is undefined. You either have to transform your data like the temperature example (set your lowest value to 0 and scale), or consider why you are using RMSLE and if it really is the right metric.

Comment: To emphasize: RMSLE is appropriate if you're trying to predict the correct order of magnitude of a variable (e.g. "is it in the hunderds or in thousands"). When your variable is *temperature* (degrees Kelvin), as in the example, this is rarely the case - when you're working with temperatures, you usually care about the absolute difference and not just the order of magnitude. A good example where RMSLE is appropriate is the "Boston housing prices" dataset from Kaggle.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, one of the predictions was negative, although all of the training target values were positive. I narrowed this down to outliers and solved it by using the [RobustScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.RobustScaler.html) from sklearn. Which not only scales the data but also deals with outliers

> Scale features using statistics that are robust to outliers.

Answer (score 0):

Feature scaling should be a good option here, such that the minimum value is >= 0.

Answer (score 0):

Use min-max scaler to scale your value between (0, x], where x is anything you choose. Then use this for better result.